# How to select/unselect multiple CheckBoxes by specific checkbox names on Button Click

Tags: javascript, html

What would be an easy way to select multiple checkboxes (not all) with a click of a button?

Any suggestion on how to make this easily?

Thanks,
EraNet

```js
function Select() {
  var items = document.getElementsByName('Red')
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type == 'checkbox')
      items[i].checked = true;
  }

}

function UnSelect() {
  var items = document.getElementsByName('Red')
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type == 'checkbox')
      items[i].checked = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="Red" value="Red">Red<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Blue" value="Blue">Blue<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Yellow" value="Yellow">Yellow<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Orange" value="Orange">Orange<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Pink" value="Pink">Pink<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Voilet" value="Voilet">Voilet<br>
<p>
  <input type="button" onclick='Select()' value="Select" />
  <input type="button" onclick='UnSelect()' value="Unselect" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a class name for selecting some/all and then using `querySelectorAll()` to select the elements that need change.

### Update

I extended the example with more "select buttons", so that you can see that `querySelectorAll()` is flexible in the input elements that you would like to update.

```js
function Select(str) {
  UnSelect();
  // all input elements that has the class name "one"
  var items = document.querySelectorAll(str);
  items.forEach(item => item.checked = true);
}

function UnSelect() {
  // all input elements that has a name
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('input[name]');
  items.forEach(item => item.checked = false);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="one" name="Red" value="Red">Red<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="one" name="Blue" value="Blue">Blue<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="one three" name="Yellow" value="Yellow">Yellow<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="two three" name="Orange" value="Orange">Orange<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="two" name="Pink" value="Pink">Pink<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="two" name="Voilet" value="Voilet">Voilet<br>
<p>
  <input type="button" onclick="Select('input.one')" value="Select by classname 'one'" />
  <input type="button" onclick="Select(`input[name = 'Blue']`)" value="Select by name 'Blue'" />
  <input type="button" onclick="Select(`input[name = 'Blue'],input[name = 'Pink']`)" value="Select by name 'Blue' and 'Pink'" />
  <input type="button" onclick="Select(`input.three`)" value="Select by classname 'three'" />
  <input type="button" onclick='UnSelect()' value="Unselect" />
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The reason I would like to have it by name is that I migh have 4 buttons and each button will tick a different combination of boxes. So it will need to be a list of selected names for each button and one button to unselected all.

Thanks, EraNet

Comment: Not sure why, but I am not able to run this in a hta file...